# Computation of a 2D limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I came across this limit and I used Mathematica to solve it, (it shows that it is equal to $0$).

Any thoughts on how to prove this ? The limit is:

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (4,0)} \frac{y^2(x^2+y^2)}{(x-4)^2+y^2}$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x-4\to 0$ then

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (4,0)} \frac{y^2(x^2+y^2)}{(x-4)^2+y^2}=\lim \limits_{(u,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{y^2((u+4)^2+y^2)}{u^2+y^2}$$

and for

- $y=0$

$$\frac{y^2((u+4)^2+y^2)}{u^2+y^2}=0$$

but for

- $u=y$

$$\frac{u^2((u+4)^2+u^2)}{2u^2}=\frac{2u^2+8u+16}{2}=u^2+4u+8\to 8$$

therefore the given limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. Can we then say something about the $\limsup$ ?

Comment: By polar coordinates we obtain $$\frac{y^2((u+4)^2+y^2)}{u^2+y^2}=\sin^2 \theta(r^2+8\cos \theta +16)$$ and we can find the maximum for $f(\theta)=\sin^2 \theta(8\cos \theta +16)$.

Comment: I think it's $\sin^2\theta (r^2+8r\cos\theta+16).$ Anyway my original problem was to prove that this specific function is bounded on a domain that has $(4,0)$ on its boundary so I should prove that the $\limsup$ is bounded and this comes easily from polar coordinates ?

Comment: @Curtis74 Yes of course sorry, we have indeed $\frac{y^2((u+4)^2+y^2)}{u^2+y^2}=\sin^2 \theta(r^2+8r\cos \theta +16)$. Yes in any case the expression is bounded, indeed $|\sin^2 \theta(r^2+8r\cos \theta +16)|\le |r^2+8r+16|$.